# Why Kafka Producer Publishing String Message with Double Quotes in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

I am trying to publish String Message into Kafka Topic in Spring Boot.

I want to publish message without double quotes in Kafka topic like as shown below:

`IN|TN|2021-03-03 15:22:04.000400|2021-03-03T15:22:09.370002|00000002810000149059|1|8888888888`

but it is publishing in Kafka topic with double quotes like as shown below:

`"IN|TN|2021-03-03 15:22:04.000400|2021-03-03T15:22:09.370002|00000002810000149059|1|8888888888"`

and using `producer.key-serializer` is `StringDeserializer`
and `producer.value-serializer` is `JsonSerializer` and also tried value-serializer with `StringSerializer` even issue is still persists.

## Code as below:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, this.topicSender)
                .build();

kafkaTemplate.send(message);
```

Can anyone please help me here that to publish string message without quotes in Kafka topic.

Comment: Why are you using `JsonSerializer`? That's just a log String. Json would require fields and values to be in quotes.

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Configure the producer value serializer as **StringSerializer**

```
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```